# docker container using nfs directory on remote host as volume

Tags: docker

I have an application in my local host.
The application use files from directory on remote host as data base.
I should docker this application 
How can I use this directory? 
I tried to use it as volume but it didn't work
the files of the directory are inside container, but the application doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow map remote directory into your local host, why not using the same technique inside docker?

If for some reasons you cant (lets say, you don't want to install additional drivers in your container), you still can use volumes:

Lets say on your local host your directory (which is somehow synchronized with remote endpoint) is called `/home/sync_folder`. Then you start `docker` in following manner:

```
docker run -it -v /home/sync_folder:/shares ubuntu ls /shares
```

I've written `ubuntu` just as an example. `ls /shares` illustrates ow to access directory inside container